# How to store Condition in a column in Database

Tags: laravel, conditional-statements, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

I want to store condition in database.

Each row of a certain table contains a specific condition involving its columns

Ex,.

```
table_name 
  value_x
  value_y
  condition
  result
```

Then for querying

```
$condition = TableName::find($id)->condtion;
$resultSet = TableName::whereRaw($condition)->get();
```

I know this code is silly, but i hope you get the point.

Comment: can you elaborate ! Something like what the data looks like

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working for you? Why would you wish to store a *'raw SQL query condition'* in the database to begin with?

Comment: @xenooooo the condition column can play around the two columns (value_x, value_y) it depends on the condition column what logic it contains